# Right way to force grails upgrade a library used by a plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, flying-saucer

I am using the [Rendering plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rendering) of Grails to render PDF pages but there apparently is a problem with flying-saucer version included in the render 0.4.4. 
I would like to use the render but force grails upgrade flying-sauce-pdf directly.

My BuildConfig.groovy looks like:

```
plugins {
..
        compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.0.4'
        compile (":rendering:0.4.4") { excludes "flying-saucer-pdf" }
}
```

The error getting is:

```
[FAILED     ] org.xhtmlrenderer#flying-saucer-pdf;9.0.4!flying-saucer-pdf.zip:  (0ms)
==== grailsPlugins: tried
...
```

Looks like I am doing something wrong in including flying-saucer-pdf directly. What is the correct way of invoking it to be compiled with the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that flying-saucer-pdf is a library not a plugin, so you should put it into dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.0.4'       
}
```